# Can you set a task ratio for TaskSet(s) in Locust Python

Tags: python, locust

```
class UserBehavior1(TaskSet):
        @task
        def task1:...

        @task
        def task2:...

class UserBehavior2(TaskSet):
        @task
        def task1:...

        @task
        def task2:...

class User(HttpUser):
        wait_time = between(n,m)
        host = 'https://example.com'
        tasks = [UserBehavior1, UserBehavior2]
```

Is there a way to specify a ratio for TaskSet(s) in Locust? I'm aware that the @task decorator takes in an additional argument to add weight but I'm not sure if it would work in this case. I want the tasks within each TaskSet to be weighted equally but I want the TaskSet(s) to be performed with different ratios (let's say 2:5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TaskSets can also be weighted with the same `@task` decorator as individual tasks, as explained in the [TaskSet docs](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/tasksets.html), and you can weight them that way. Alternatively, the docs also explain that the [`tasks attribute`](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#id2) can be defined as a dictionary instead of a list and you can give a weight with them, even for TaskSets. Applied to your sample code, it would look like this:

```
class User(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(n,m)
    host = 'https://example.com'
    tasks = {UserBehavior1: 2, UserBehavior2: 5}
```

This should give your TaskSets a weighting of 2:5 each time a user is spawned. The individual tasks in the TaskSets then have their own weighting.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Their is another way to distribute ratio among taskset if you want to run four class in such a ratio 4:3:2:1

it means that class1 task goes to 4 request, class2 task goes to 3 request, class3 task goes to 2 request and class4 task goes to only 1 request

```
class1_ratio=4
class2_ratio=3
class3_ratio=2
class4_ratio=1

class class_name1(TaskSet):
        @task
        def task1:...
class class_name2(TaskSet):
        @task
        def task2:...
class class_name3(TaskSet):
        @task
        def task3:...
class class_name4(TaskSet):
        @task
        def task4:...

class UserBehaviour(TaskSet):
        tasks={
               class_name1:class1_ratio,
               class_name2:class2_ratio,
               class_name3:class3_ratio,
               class_name4:class4_ratio}

class LoggedInUser(HttpUser):
        tasks = [UserBehaviour]
```